# Firebase Deployment Failed?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am try to deploy my function but this keep failing.

Currently The Function is deploy on NodeJS 10. I Reworked the code and deployed with Node Version 12.

I am using CLI of firebase.

The deploy failed and asked to check the log in cloud console and this was the log:

```
{
  "textPayload": "ERROR: build step 2 \"us.gcr.io/fn-img/buildpacks/nodejs10/builder:nodejs10_20210505_10_24_1_RC00\" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1",
  "insertId": "c3362881-be3d-4d52-965d-84793fde26ed-174",
  "resource": {
    "type": "build",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "ecutter",
      "build_id": "c3362881-be3d-4d52-965d-84793fde26ed",
      "build_trigger_id": ""
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-05-24T19:49:39.640786230Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "labels": {
    "build_step": "MAIN"
  },
  "logName": "projects/ecutter/logs/cloudbuild",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-05-24T19:49:39.769241759Z"
}
```

**What i tried ?**

At first i deployed the function and it failed.

I thought it could be becz of node version so i tried to update the node version of deployed function from cloud console but it failed.

Tried Reinstalling Node Versions npm modules but none helped.

What's going on ?

Comment: You can only node version 10, on free plan, if you are using upgraded  plan then you can use node version 12.

Comment: I am on blaze plan. Firebase now don't offer Functions in free tier.

Comment: did you check logs files, which is on remote server, provide more info ?

Comment: I've already added the information which was provided in logs

Comment: @ChandraShekharAazad did you check with lint issue ?

Comment: it seems you are still building with node 10 `/buildpacks/nodejs10/builder`

Comment: can you try building with `--debug` and post the log?

Comment: @DIGIByte I didn't asked any specific things while deploying. I used normal node envirement and deployed it. But it failed.  I created a folder moved things from there to here and deployed successfully.